# Validate Script tag within XHTML

Tags: javascript

The "span" tag is invalid, how do I make it valid?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

...

<script type="text/javascript">
  var locations = [
    [
      'Kirklevington Village Hall',
      '<span style="font-size:2;"><b>Kirklevington Village Hall</b>,<br />Forest Lane,<br />Kirklevington,<br />Stockton&nbsp;on&nbsp;tees,<br />TS15&nbsp;9LX</span>',
      54.4825,
      -1.33663
    ]
  ];
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose your script in `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` to make it appear as a comment to the validator.

More info [here](http://dorward.me.uk/www/comments-cdata/)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to put the script code to a separate file, say foo.js, and refer to it using `<script "src=foo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. Other methods involve various techniques for “escaping” the content of the `script` element, and they are clumsy and error-prone.

The XHTML 1.0 spec, [appendix C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_4), recommends: “Use external scripts if your script uses `<` or `&` or `]]>` or `--`.”